# shadow-root: is there a way to include an external javascript file into a shadow-root?

Tags: javascript, external, shadow-dom

Say I have a few js-files stored externally, or I just want to load a new dependency like JQuery or Angular in my shadow-root, is there a way to load it into it?

I know for css-stylesheets you can just do:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('type','text/css');
    style.innerText = '@import "' + csspath + '";';
```

is there a similar way to do that with js?
Since just doing this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = jspath;
```

**doesn't work :/**

Also I am doing this:

```
var root = document.getElementById('container').createShadowRoot(); 
var DOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html.responseText,'text/html').getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

DOM.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

the "parseFromString(html.responseText,'text/html')" is because I am getting my html from an external source as well.

Here is a plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/YM1lXN8QEhjMd4n9u0wf?p=preview

Comment: The code works (apart from a typo at the end of the first line). When you want to execute the script, you've to append it to `body` or `head`, though. For this you've to keep a reference to the `script` alive.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what to do... I thought I did append, by doing `.appendChild(script)`

Comment: Ah not on the real page, I just wrote something random here.

Comment: @Teemu I added a plunkr to show what I have

Comment: Hmmm... AJAX is an abbreviation of Asynchronous Javascript And Xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kinda figured this out,
I didn't understand what a #shadow-root is.
Its not like an iFrame where it gets its own #document and has a completely different environment to the rest of the site.
You can load js into a shadow-root by calling its parent element and then its elements,
So say this is my structure:

```
div [id='app']
|   #shadow-root
|   |   div [id='content']
```

then in order to work some magic on the '#content' tag, using jquery you can change it by doing this:

```
$('#app').find('#content').html('hello world')
```

**Even if this code is ran from inside the shadow-root**

Answer (score 3):

As you figured out, Shadow DOM does not create a new scope for JavaScript, it's only concerned with DOM and CSS scoping.

There are a couple approaches to adding JavaScript to the document. The first is the classic script injection:

```
<script>
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//somehost.com/awesome-widget.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

You were doing this in your previous example but you were appending the script to the wrong place. Just add it to the main `document` instead of the html that you loaded. I think it should work in either instance, but it makes more sense for it to follow the typical pattern of appending to the main document's `head`.

The other approach, if you're using HTML Imports, is to include a `link` tag, which has a `script` that points to your resource. This is often what we do with Polymer elements. [We link all of our dependencies at the top](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-tabs/blob/master/paper-tabs.html#L84-L87), that way they get loaded before our element definition is registered.